# Why the child element does not take margin relative to parent

Tags: html, css, margin

I am providing the child `<p>` inside a `<div>` element a margin, but it is shifting the div element itself. I want to shift down the paragraph to an arbitrary value. I know we can provide padding to parent element, but what about it?

Here, take this example code... Try changing the `.square p` margin property.

```css
*{
  margin: 20px auto;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f56;
} .square p {
  margin: 50px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"><p>Hi</p></div>
```

Shouldn't it be relative to the parent element?

Answer (score 1):

`p` is a `block` element and this behaviour is expected as the parent `square` is too.

Try `inline-block` display for the `p` tag and you can adjust margins relative the parent. If you want to keep `p` as a `block`, you should be giving `overflow: hidden` for the parent.

Example using `inline-block`:

```css
*{
  margin: 20px auto;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f56;
} .square p {
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"><p>Hi</p></div>
```

Comment: Yes, this works. But why do we require a fix, this is a thing that W3C has to look. Anyway, what's the benefit of margin-collapsing?

Comment: I'm not an expert. @NenadVracar should know about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is parent-child [`margin collapsing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) . One way to fix it is to use `overflow: hidden`

```css
* {
  margin: 20px auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f56;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.square p {
  margin: 50px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <p>Hi</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give `display:inline-block;` property to child `p`.

```css
*{
  margin: 20px auto;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f56;
}
.square p {
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"><p>Hi</p></div>
```